# linear world clock using Flash/Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, clock

I am trying to create a linear clock that gets the time from the users computer and displays that time on a world map that is seperated up into 24 hours and has those hours marked out along the base of the movie. A red line would indicate current time (in the viewers time zone). Also ideally if each hour could be divided in such a way so that the map didn't just jump from 1 hour to the next, maybe each hour divided into 12 to give 5 minute increments on each hour.

The grey/blue bars over the map will represent the financial markets opening and closing and this I will create using masking layers.

I understand a little about actionscript but I am by no means an expert. I guess the easiest way I can think to do this is to create a looping tween from one end of the "clock" to the other and then use actionscript to get the users time and go to a corresponding frame based on that time. If anyone knows of a simpler way, I would be very eager to hear it.

Comment: show us your codes, and probably & preferrably screenshot too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that`s an intersting task, and can be done the way you proposed, however i would do it purely in as3 with doing tweens programatically, because of much more control over it.  In either cases  take care that the World time zones aren't linear per meridians - so the time change isn't equal on all places spanning the same meridian,  there are axceptions, in fact many of them, that will complicate the implementation of your clock, but can be done.  Statically  implementing your markets with their respective time zones would save you some coding time. .. but then if you want some more universal solution for further usage,  your clock should be smarter and more sugar is needed, obviously :)